# double strike one or identity matrix

Tags: lyx

I want to write the double strike 1 in lyx,

[image: d]

but when I write,

\ensuremath{\mathbb{1}}, I am getting, [image: d]

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're encountering is that the font that contains the uppercase letters for `\mathbb` also contains other symbols in the non-uppercase letter slots so it is giving you the `\nVdash` symbol.

A symbol similar to what you want is available using

```
\usepackage{dsfont}

$\mathds{1}$
```

Another option is to use the `unicode-math` package and

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

$\symbb{1}$
```

although this may be a bigger commitment than you want to make see [the documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In LyX's math mode, you can just type `\mathds{1}` (LyX will take care of loading the dsfont package). Equivalently, in math mode, you can click on the math fonts toolbar icon and then "Double stroke" and then type "1".